# Как пишется название праздника "старый Новый год"?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Здравствуйте, знатоки! Вопрос простой, но ответ на него не найден. Итак, как пишется название праздника "старый Новый год"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае название праздника двойное. И, поскольку, по правилам первое слово названия праздника пишется с большой буквы, но тут будет с большой и "старый", и "новый!. То есть - "Старый Новый год".

Answer (score 1):

старый Новый год.

Answer (score 1):

Все-таки по словарным рекомендациям "старый Новый год". "Новый год" — название праздника, а "старый" — просто прилагательное, к названию праздника не имеющее отношения. Это, видимо, логика словаристов. 
Я испытываю некоторый дискомфорт от такой трактовки, но придется подчиниться.

Answer (score 0):

Старый Новый год –– самый правильный вариант.

Прилагательное **старый** пишется с прописной буквы, так как является началом предложения. 
Прилагательное **новый** пишется с большой буквы постольку, поскольку в поздравительном выражении "Поздравляю с Новым годом" пишется с прописной буквы.

Думаю, что мой вариант весьма правильный. Однако если найдутся те, кто думают иначе, то, пожалуйста, высказывайтесь.

Comment: Вы правильно выбрали форму написания, но объяснение не совсем корректное. 
Выбор прописной буквы  в  слове «Старый» не определяется началом предложения, в любом положении запись будет одинаковой, например: «Вы отмечаете Старый Новый год»?
 «Старый Новый год «– это составное имя собственное, и входящие в него  слова  могут писаться как с прописной, так и со строчной буквы.   Поэтому  статус каждого слова  нужно определять отдельно.  «Старый» – это первое слово  составного названия,  поэтому пишется с прописной буквы.  «Новый год» –  входящее имя собственное, которое пишется по своим правилам.

Answer (score 0):

Словарная фиксация: старый Новый год. См.: Лопатин В. В., Нечаева И. В., Чельцова Л. К. Прописная или строчная? Орфографический словарь. М., 2011.

Comment: А как бы его посмотреть в сети? --- Хотя, впрочем, не надо. Да, Лопатин последовательно настаивает на строчной. Но я не уверен, что он в том не одинок.